# Creating a collection of DOMDocument

Tags: xml, vba, excel, domdocument

I have a macro where the user is supposed to select .xml files in a folder, the number of files is not determined.

In those .xml, there are two nodes categories :

- F1 nodes that are information node
- F2 nodes that delete some of the nodes of previous files (not all of them).

Once i have loaded my .xml files, i have to :

- search for F2 nodes, then locate the targeted F1 nodes and .remove them, then .remove the F2 Nodes to keep only the "valid" F1 nodes in my files.
- Then I want to analyse the remaining valid nodes.

My problem is to load and then store each selected file as a DOMDocument. I was thinking of using a collection or an array, but neither works as the Object is passed Byref and I end up with a collection storing x time the last .xml loaded.

What i (really) want to do :

- Pass the DOMDocument byval to a collection or array of some sort for modification

What i cannot do, or try to avoid :

- I can't modify the .xml files.
- I would very much like to avoid copying the .xml to a technical folder for modification as, in the end, this macro will be modified to, instead of using a user input, parse through about 200 folders with many files in each and 1) this will probably decreased heavily performances and 2) I might have autorisation problem in the operating environment of this macro.

I have searched with various keywords on stackoverflow and google and i can't seem to find a solution.

The "Microsoft XML, v6.0" library is added to my library reference.

```vb
Dim xmlDoc as DOMDocument
Dim SelFiles As FileDialogSelectedItems
Dim nFile as long
Dim coDocXML As New Collection

Set SelFiles = InputFilesDial("xml", "*.xml", True)

For nFile = 1 to SelFiles.Count
    If xmlDoc.Load(SelFiles(nFile)) Then
        coDocXML.Add Item:=xmlDoc
    End If
Next nFile

Function InputFilesDial(stDescription As String, stFilter, multiSel As Boolean, Optional stPath As String) As FileDialogSelectedItems

    Dim FileDial As Office.FileDialog
    If Not stPath Like vbNullString Then ChDir (stPath)

    Set FileDial = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With FileDial
        .AllowMultiSelect = multiSel
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add Description:=stDescription, Extensions:=stFilter
        .Show
    End With

    Set InputFilesDial = FileDial.SelectedItems

End Function
```

Comment: You are asking too many questions at the end, some of which are too general and broad without knowing what is being *modified*. Your first issue should be the primary question. Please share the `InputFilesDial` method.

Comment: Hello. I've edited my question to try to clarify, is it better?
Sorry, not a CS or even a native english speaker so i'm having a hard time making myself clear.

Comment: @AlexP, just for interest: what is `InputFilesDial`? - Is this a user defined function, as I never heard of it.

Comment: @T.M. yes, it's homemade :D as Parfait wisely remarked, it lacks the error handling because I'm lazy, i will implement it.

Comment: Just for the art: would it be possible you show it (even without error handling) in an edit as addendum to your OP (might help others, too)? - One final hint: as you are using early binding with reference to "Microsoft XML, v6.0", I would prefer to declare all XML docs as corresponding `MSXML2.DOMDocument60` (i.e. latest version, instead of `DOMDocument` only).

Comment: `InputFilesDial` is at the end of the code, just after `next nFile`. I've tried to use `MSXML2.DOMDocument60` but i can't seem to use Xpath Query then, because my .xml uses prefix (`ftc:` and `sfa:`) : i can have the following code `Set listNode = tDocXML.SelectNodes("//ftc:AccountReport")` with old `DOMDocument`, but i get an error with `DOMDocument60` because i haven't defined a prefix. What do you think?

Comment: Say your have a root node `<root xmlns="...">`, then you find the name space string within the `xmlns` attribute. 
Add the following to  the loading routine: `XMLNameSpaces = "xmlns:doc='...'"` and 
`xDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", XMLNameSpaces`. Then you have to add `doc:` as a prefix to all your node selects, e.g. 
`xDoc.selectSingleNode("//doc:myNode/doc:mySubnode`")`. Sure you find some examples at SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply reset the `xmlDoc` object within the loop and add a `Else` handler for files that failed to parse. Items in Debug.Print window (Ctrl + G) will output which files raised parsing errors:

```vb
Sub RunXML()
    Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument
    Dim SelFiles As FileDialogSelectedItems
    Dim nFile As Long
    Dim coDocXML As New Collection

    Set SelFiles = InputFilesDial("xml", "*.xml", True)

    For nFile = 1 To SelFiles.Count
        Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument             ' RESET xmlDoc OBJECT

        If xmlDoc.Load(SelFiles(nFile)) Then
            coDocXML.Add Item:=xmlDoc
        Else
            Debug.Print SelFiles(nFile), xmlDoc.parseError
        End If
    Next nFile

    Set SelFiles = Nothing
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Great to hear! Glad to help!

Comment: edit : just to understand better how it works : when you reset a variable, it doesn't erase the object added to a collection although it's Byref?

Comment: More or less yes. Before, the same *xmlDoc* object was used in every item of collection. With each iteration of loop, you simply updated all same objects at once. In fact, this is even new to me as I did not think VBA collections saved pointers of object and would update items within with each change of object.

Comment: Appreciate your mentioning `parseError` information +:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach allowing multiselect. After adding to collection you can reference your XML files via `xDoc1`, `xDoc2` ...:

**Code**

```vb
Option Explicit
  Dim coDocXML As New Collection
' Declare xDoc variable as of type DOMDocument60
  Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60 

Sub test_xmlcol()
'  Declare a variable to contain the path of each selected item. 
'  Even though the path is aString, the variable must be a Variant because 
'  For Each...Next routines only work with Variants and Objects.
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
dim cnt   As Integer
'Declare a variable as a FileDialog object.
Dim cnt   As Integer
Dim fd    As FileDialog
'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
 Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
' Set xDoc to memory
  Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60               
  xDoc.validateOnParse = False
' allow XPath (if DOMDocument vers. 3.0, can omit it if vers. 6.0)
  xDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"


'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
With fd

    'Allow the selection of multiple file.
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    'Add a filter that includes GIF and JPEG images and make it the first item in the list.
     .Filters.Add "XML-Files", "*.xml", 1
    'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
    'The user pressed the button.
    If .Show = -1 Then

          'Step through each string in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection
          For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
            cnt = cnt + 1
            'vrtSelectedItem is aString that contains the path of each selected item.
            'You can use any file I/O functions that you want to work with this path.
            'This example displays the path in a message box.
            MsgBox "Selected item's path: " & vrtSelectedItem
            coDocXML.Add vrtSelectedItem, "xDoc" & cnt
          Next vrtSelectedItem

    'The user pressed Cancel.
    Else
    End If
End With

' Have an informative look at every file    
For cnt = 1 To coDocXML.Count
   Debug.Print cnt, "xDoc" & cnt & ": " & coDocXML.Item("xDoc" & cnt)
Next cnt

'' load some file and do something via 
'    cnt = 1           ' only example
'    If xDoc.Load coDocXML.Item("xDoc" & cnt) then
''      ... do something
'    End If

'Set the object variable to Nothing.
Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi T.M., thanks for the code! I've added information in my question that make this answer not entirely usable for what i need to do. Still, this might prove to be my only solution.